# ClassCastException in Linux but not Windows - DefaultMutableTreeNode

Tags: java, classcastexception

Here is the problem.  I have the following class FileNode which extends DefaultMutableTreeNode

```
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import java.io.File;

public class FileNode extends  DefaultMutableTreeNode {
    public FileNode(String Name, File File) {
        super(Name);
        this.Name = Name;
        this.File = File;
        this.isFolder = false;
        CheckedOut = false;
    }

    public FileNode(String Name, File File, Boolean isFolder) {
        super(Name);
        this.Name = Name;
        this.File = File;
        this.isFolder = isFolder;
        CheckedOut = false;
    }

    public Boolean CheckedOut;
    public File File;
    public String Name;
    public Boolean isFolder;
}
```

I have a tree filled with these nodes.

I am getting a cast exception with the following:

```
private class FileTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
          boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf,
          int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf,
           row, hasFocus);
        FileNode fn = (FileNode)value;
        Color nodeColor = Color.BLACK;
        if (!fn.isFolder) {
            if (fn.CheckedOut) {
              nodeColor = Color.RED;
            } else {
              nodeColor = new Color(0,100,0);
            }
        }
        setForeground(nodeColor);
        return this;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that I only get this error in Linux not in Windows.  I am running the same JRE on both platforms - Oracle JDK 1.7.0_25

Anyone have any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

here is stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode cannot be cast to dropboxcheckout.FileNode
    at dropboxcheckout.CheckoutPanel$FileTreeCellRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(CheckoutPanel.java:115)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$NodeDimensionsHandler.getNodeDimensions(BasicTreeUI.java:2786)
    at javax.swing.tree.AbstractLayoutCache.getNodeDimensions(AbstractLayoutCache.java:492)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache$TreeStateNode.updatePreferredSize(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:1359)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.updateNodeSizes(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:917)
    at javax.swing.tree.VariableHeightLayoutCache.invalidateSizes(VariableHeightLayoutCache.java:371)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.setCellRenderer(BasicTreeUI.java:385)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.propertyChange(BasicTreeUI.java:3390)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8382)
    at javax.swing.JTree.setCellRenderer(JTree.java:759)
    at dropboxcheckout.CheckoutPanel.<init>(CheckoutPanel.java:85)
    at dropboxcheckout.CheckoutFrame.<init>(CheckoutFrame.java:37)
```

Comment: Paste in stack trace.

Comment: Could you please add the full stack trace of the Exception to your question, so we have some idea of where the problem is occurring, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a stack trace dump, its hard to see where the problem is occurring, but assuming that its in the code you've posted, I'm guessing that its probably your `FileNode` cast.

My recommendation would be to handle this exception properly, regardless of what system its running on...

```
private class FileTreeCellRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {
    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        Color nodeColor = Color.BLACK;

        if (value instanceof FileNode){
            FileNode fn = (FileNode)value;
            if (!fn.isFolder) {
                if (fn.CheckedOut) {
                    nodeColor = Color.RED;
                }
                else {
                    nodeColor = new Color(0,100,0);
                }
            }
        }

        setForeground(nodeColor);
        return this;
    }
}
```

This change will check that the `value` is a `FileNode` before performing the cast. If its not a `FileNode`, it'll paint the value in black, rather than crashing at this point.

In general, its good practice to check before doing a cast, so you can handle it correctly in the off-chance that the object isn't actually castable.

Comment: Thanks, This worked - using instanceof - and all my files come up colored.  Seems strange that it worked on Windows and not Linux.  Now it works on both.

Comment: Could you add some log to check what else is receiving that method in Linux? Now I'm curious about what class can be received to generate a CCE only in Linux

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you're happy that your problem is resolved, please "tick" the answer so everyone knows that there is a solution to your problem.

Comment: Nice solutions .... most of us really don't know the usage of instanceof operator properly. +1